# Gitlab commits match regex

Tags: regex, gitlab

I am trying to add Commit Regex Rules in Gitlab . How do I implement below pattern :

Project-1 ,Project-2-1 , Project-3 are constant words and should always be in start of the commit message followed by a space , colon , space and a sentence at the end.

```
Project-1 : Changes done to fix the issue
Project-2-1 : Code changes
Project-3 : Bug squash
```

```
\b^(Project-1|Project-2-1|Project-3)\b : \w+
```

But the above regex is not matching a sentence at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the ranges of digits you might use a character class `[1-3]` or match 1+ digits using `[0-9]+`

If the digits after Project-digit can have an optional -digit part, you could make that optional using an optional non capturing group `(?:-\d)?`

If there should be at least a non whitespace char `\S` after the last space:

```
^Project-[1-3](?:-\d)? : \S.*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bogsMZ/1)

For a broader match you could make use of a negated character class matching any char except a hypen at the beginning and match 1 or more digits:

```
^[^-]+-[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)? : \S.*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sfjJup/1)

Comment: The starting words can be anything , not just the ones mentioned above . The starting words should be always from the list of words I pass in the pattern . How to do that .

Comment: If you want to match a word, you could match 1+ word characters using `\w+` like `^\w+-[1-3](?:-\d)? : \S.*` https://regex101.com/r/jK3u9N/1 or use a negated character class matching any char except a hyphen `^[^-]+-[1-3](?:-\d)? : \S.*` https://regex101.com/r/KnxVoi/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird in your second solution, you can not force `Project` which OP seems to want. First solution is great +1.